# How to enable all HTTP methods on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, webdav

The apache server I have in my company blocks
some HTTP methods that are required for WebDav.
I would like to help my admin to enable HTTP 
methods I need. He sent me httpd.config file 
but I'm unable to find the section which blocks
methods I need (like LOCK and UNLOCK)

In directory section I have:

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Indexes,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,FollowSymLinks,None
```

My admin also have told me that he did not find .htaccess

So my question is - where does the Apache block methods I need
(does the apache enables only "default" http methods?)

And second question is - can I unlock the methods I need by
listing them in httpd.conf file in directory section, for example:

```
  <Limit GET PUT POST DELETE PROPFIND PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
  Require valid-user
  </Limit>
```

I don't want to use the mod_dav module (i want to use sabre server).
I just want to unlock http methods that are required for WebDav

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: Apache 2.4+ provide a `mod_allowmethods` to do exactly this: https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_allowmethods#allowmethods

Comment: Thank you @hjpotter92. I know about this. But is it possible to find a place where the http method I require are locked? And can I unlock them without using any other modules? Or - to put it in other words - does Apache lock some HTTP methods by default?

I found this on the website you gave:

_mod_allowmethods was written to replace the rather kludgy implementation of Limit and LimitExcept_

So I understand that it still possible to use Limit and LimitExcept to unlock methods I need. And that means that Apache blocks some methods by default. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think Apache disabled any methods on its own.