# Ionic - XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: .htaccess, http, ionic-framework, ionic2, cors

I have an Ionic PWA, so it runs in browser. I'm trying to send requests to my symfony backend. At first I had everything installed on my local pc and the requests were working with an ionic proxy. Now I have installed both applications on a server. At first I have tried to use the url from the backend without proxy. Then there was a CORS error. Then I wrote a .htaccess file for the backend with the following input:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "\*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

Now I'm getting this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   ... Response for preflight
>   has invalid HTTP status code 405

If I set a proxy as before on the local installation like this:

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://api.example.com/api"
    }
  ]
```

I'm getting a 404 not found error, when I try to send a request to http://app.example.com/api

Can someone tell me how it will work correctly when frontend and backend are on a server and the app runs in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a 405 back, that's a method not supported error, so it looks like you server isn't configured to handle OPTIONS requests. That's causing the pre-flight CORS request to get rejected.

Comment: Yes, but I have OPTIONS in my .htaccess, like you see above. Or must I do it on a different way?

Comment: You're only adding a response header above. It looks like the problem is your server isn't configured to accept OPTIONS requests. See this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696369/how-to-enable-all-http-methods-on-apache